# Extract values between two patterns

Tags: text-processing, sed, json

I am using Ubuntu and I want to extract the values between two patterns and the required string is not in the file.

My data is as shown below:

```json
[{"rows":[{"_uuid":["uuid","11111-222-33333-4444444"]}]}]
```

I want to get the text between `,` and `]`, and that means I want `11111-222-33333-444444`. How can I do this using `sed`?

1. [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) is the operating system I'm using.
2. It was not stored in any file or variable. It was the output of one command. I want to pipe the output of command1 to sed and parse the above string to get only the required information.
3. It was in [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format. This was the only data we would be getting...

Answer (score 12):

Using `jq` (which does not care whether the input is in compact or multi-line form):

```bash
your-command | jq -r '.[0].rows[0]._uuid[1]'
```

Your JSON document is an array consisting of objects and you want the first of these top-level objects, `.[0]`. That object contains a `rows` array, and you want the first of its elements, `.rows[0]`. That element has another array called `_uuid`, and you want that array's second element, `._uuid[1]`.

With `-r` you get the decoded, "raw", data back. Without `-r`, you get a (quoted) JSON string.

---

A totally different way of getting the data from this *particular* JSON document would be to get *the last value* in the document:

```bash
your-command | jq -r 'getpath([paths(scalars)][-1])'
```

This first generates all "paths" for each scalar value in the whole document with `paths`, and picks out the last of them.  The expression then uses this path-of-the-last-scalar with `getpath` to pull out the last value.  For the given document, this results in the expected output.

The following is probably doing the same thing, but with explicit recursion using `..` and with `select()` to pull out all scalar values:

```bash
your-command | jq -r '[.. | select(scalars)][-1]'
```

Personally, I would go with the topmost suggestion in this answer, as it uses the structure of the document, which is bound to be meaningful to the user in some way.  That code would have to be revisited, and the question reformulated, if any of the involved arrays starts containing more elements.

Answer (score 4):

If we can be certain that there is *always* only one `,` per line, and you want everything between that `,` and the first `]` that comes after it, you can use `sed`:

```
 $ echo '[{"rows":[{"_uuid":["uuid","11111-222-33333-4444444"]}]}]' | sed 's/.*,\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/'
"11111-222-33333-4444444"
```

or, to also avoid the quotes:

```
   $ echo '[{"rows":[{"_uuid":["uuid","11111-222-33333-4444444"]}]}]' | sed 's/.*,"\([^]]*\)"\].*/\1/'
11111-222-33333-4444444
```

However, since this looks like JSON data, you should not use `sed` as this solution will break with even the smallest change in the input format. You should [use a dedicated JSON parser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/680377/22222) like `jq` instead.

Comment: how can we use jq for the same problem statement

Comment: @KattaSivasai I don't know `jq` well enough to answer, sorry. As for the `'` yes, you could remove it in this specific case, but don't: it is a good habit to always quote anything you pass to `echo` so that it is protected from the shell.

Comment: thanks @terdon for your valuable answers.

Comment: @KattaSivasai In some shells, depending on the shell's settings, an unquoted globbing pattern (which is what `[...]` would be interpreted as) would cause an error if the pattern does not match anything.  This is the default in the `zsh` shell and would be the case in `bash` if the shell's `failglob` shell option was set. With `nullglob` set in `bash`, the string would disappear entirely if it does not match any filenames.

Comment: @they actually and intriguingly enough, with bash, `echo [{...}] | jq` (using the OP's string) fails with `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 7` but `echo '[{..}]' | jq` works fine. Presumably because `echo foo"bar"baz` results in `foobarbaz`, so the double quotes are being removed.

Comment: Yes, double quotes are removed by the shell if you don't quote them. The keys in the JSON document needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

If your valuable data contains just numbers and -, you can use this. (If uuid longer than 23, no problem.)

```bsh
echo '[{"rows":[{"_uuid":["uuid","11111-222-33333-4444444"]}]}]' | sed  -n "s/.*,\"\([0-9-]\{23,\}\)\"].*/\1/p"
```

Output :
11111-222-33333-4444444

Comment: Thanks for all your quick responces,  it's very helful

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -MJSON::Tiny -e 'from-json($_)[0].<rows>[0].<_uuid>[1].put given slurp();'  file
```

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Regarding command-line flags, calling `raku --help` at the shell command line tells us:

- The `-e` flag executes the (following) 'one-liner' program, with `strict` enabled by default.
- The `-M` flag loads a module prior to running the 'one-liner' program, in this case the `JSON::Tiny` module.

Sample Input:

```
[{"rows":[{"_uuid":["uuid","11111-222-33333-4444444"]}]}]
```

Sample Output:

```
11111-222-33333-4444444
```

According to the module home pages (first and second links below), *"`JSON::Tiny` implements RFC7159, which is a superset of ECMA-404, in that it permits any value as a top-level JSON string, not just arrays and objects."* The OP's input can be round-tripped using `from-json` and `to-json` module functions.

Please note this Raku answer, specifically the `[0].<rows>[0].<_uuid>[1]` descent into the `JSON` structure, bears striking similarity to the excellent *first* `jq` answer posted by @Kusalananda.

https://raku.land/cpan:MORITZ/JSON::Tiny
https://github.com/moritz/json
https://raku.org